# Nginx HHVM with Laravel returning 404 File Not Found

Tags: laravel, nginx, hhvm

I've just set HVVM on debian machine. My issue is that when I access a laravel route it returns this strange message: 404 File Not Found , however, if I make a new .php file in the public directory of the laravel, everything works safe and sound. Here are my nginx and hhvm conf files:

**hhvm.conf:**

```
    location ~ \.(hh|php)$ {
    fastcgi_keep_conn on;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

**nginx configuration:**

```
    server {
            # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
            server_name ***;

            gzip on;
            gzip_comp_level 2;
            gzip_http_version 1.0;
            gzip_proxied any;
            gzip_min_length 1100;
            gzip_buffers 16 8k;
            gzip_types text/plain text/html text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

            # Disable for IE < 6 because there are some known problems
            gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6].(?!.*SV1)";

            # Add a vary header for downstream proxies to avoid sending cached gzipped files to IE6
            gzip_vary on;

            listen 80 default_server;


            root /var/www/***/public_html/laravel/public;
            index index.php index.html index.htm;


            location / {
                    try_files $uri $uri/ index.php?$query_string;
            }

            include hhvm.conf;

            location /doc/ {
                    alias /usr/share/doc/;
                    autoindex on;
                    allow 127.0.0.1;
                    allow ::1;
                    deny all;
 }
}
```

So what may be wrong?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well, in my case the problem was the nginx block configuration.

Replacing:

```
location / {
                    try_files $uri $uri/ index.php?$query_string;
            }
```

with:

```
 location / {
        try_files \$uri \$uri/ /index.php?\$query_string;
    }
```

did the trick.